# What is the best to integrate "Direct message" functionality in django?

Tags: python, django

I just need the simple client server direct messaging in django and not getting what is the best and efficient way to do. I don't want to implement django channels as I think this is complex and provides extra functionaly which I don't need.

One article that I found useful was and wanted: https://pypi.org/project/django-directmessages/

But implementing it cause different issues like :

```
cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'
```

I have found that this is not supporting django 3.0.2 which I have. So can anyone explain me some simple way to implement some direct message functionality? Any custom db model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check [this](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) out. If you want messages to be 'instant' you may check [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If these two don't really help, you may want to create your own structure like I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582210/6063532).